# Issue with angular-cli build for jsp pages

Tags: angular, jsp, webkit, angular-cli

In angular-cli.json file I have configured my index file as "home.jsp". But in that jsp file there are few Java imports for user session like this

```
<%@page import="com.marketplace.user.auth.UserSession"%>
```

or if the file contains any

```
"${pageContext.request.contextPath}"
"<%=request.getContextPath()%>"
```

So whenever I do ng build, the compiler keeps throwing errors.

```
ERROR in   Error: Child compilation failed:
  Module build failed: SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

  - Function

  - lodash.js:14843 
    [excellor.b2b]/[lodash]/lodash.js:14843:16

  - lodash.js:494 apply
    [excellor.b2b]/[lodash]/lodash.js:494:27

  - lodash.js:15227 
    [excellor.b2b]/[lodash]/lodash.js:15227:16

  - lodash.js:496 apply
    [excellor.b2b]/[lodash]/lodash.js:496:27

  - lodash.js:6600 
    [excellor.b2b]/[lodash]/lodash.js:6600:16

  - lodash.js:14842 Function.template
    [excellor.b2b]/[lodash]/lodash.js:14842:20


  - SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

  - compiler.js:76 
    [excellor.b2b]/[html-webpack-plugin]/lib/compiler.js:76:16

  - Compiler.js:291 Compiler.<anonymous>
    [excellor.b2b]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:291:10

  - Compiler.js:494 
    [excellor.b2b]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:494:13

  - Tapable.js:202 next
    [excellor.b2b]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:202:11

  - CachePlugin.js:62 Compiler.<anonymous>
    [excellor.b2b]/[webpack]/lib/CachePlugin.js:62:5

  - Tapable.js:206 Compiler.applyPluginsAsyncSeries
    [excellor.b2b]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:206:13

  - Compiler.js:491 
    [excellor.b2b]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:491:10

  - Tapable.js:195 Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries
    [excellor.b2b]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:195:46

  - Compilation.js:645 self.applyPluginsAsync.err
    [excellor.b2b]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:645:19

  - Tapable.js:195 Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries
    [excellor.b2b]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:195:46

  - Compilation.js:636 self.applyPluginsAsync.err
    [excellor.b2b]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:636:11

  - Tapable.js:195 Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries
    [excellor.b2b]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:195:46

  - Compilation.js:631 self.applyPluginsAsync.err
    [excellor.b2b]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:631:10

  - Tapable.js:195 Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries
    [excellor.b2b]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:195:46

  - Compilation.js:627 sealPart2
    [excellor.b2b]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:627:9

  - Tapable.js:195 Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries
    [excellor.b2b]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:195:46
```

What can I do here? If it's not possible, suggest a work around.

Comment: well this code should be compiled by the servlet